# Failing to pass Grok match results to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, match, grok

I needs some assistance with Grok. I am getting "_grokparsefailure" error on logstash using filebeats input.

> filter { grok { match => [ "message" , "%{TIME:TimeStarted} %{SPACE} %{WORD:ServerName} %{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE:ProgramName} %{SPACE} %{WORD:T} %{SPACE} %{INT:SCR}%{SPACE} %{INT:WorkProcesses} %{SPACE} %{USERNAME:SystemUser} %{SPACE} %{INT:ResponseTime} %{SPACE} %{INT:TimeInWp} %{SPACE} %{INT:WaitTime} %{SPACE} %{INT:CPUTime} %{SPACE} %{INT:DBTime} %{SPACE} %{INT:VMCElapsedTime} %{SPACE} %{BASE16FLOAT:MemoryUsed} %{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE:DataTransfered}" ]
>
> named_captures_only => true } date { match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ] } }

Used the debug, all ok. Output looks good on stdout, just not loading to elasticsearch.

Comment: Are you sure ["message", "pattern"] is correct? Use { "message" => "pattern" } instead

Comment: I used that as well, but the full message is saved in the "message" field in elasticsearch. I want to create and write the data in the individual fields in the index ===============grok { match => { "message" => "%{TIME:TimeStarted} %{SPACE} ......" }===and still get the "_grokparsefailure" error

Comment: looks like your pattern does not match your input. have you tried debugging it via https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ ? are you using beats as input?

Comment: Yes I debugged it, all was ok and yes, am using filebeats for the input

Comment: At this point I can only suggest you to take a look at the logstash logs (debug level) and/or at the filebeat logs. I experienced something similar when filebeats was sending some escaped character instead of a quotation mark....